# How to fetch data with ajax call in Django and Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using wagtail with Python and Django.

I have model as follows:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    logo = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    banner_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['vehicles'] = get_vehicles("nl")[0:12]
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldRowPanel([ImageChooserPanel('logo', classname="col4")]classname="full"),
        FieldRowPanel([FieldPanel('banner_text', classname="full") classname="full")
    ]
```

And `get_vehicles("nl")` is as follows:

```
def get_vehicles(lang):
    response = requests.get(API_URL, headers={'Authorization': "Token {}".format(token), "Accept-Language": lang})
    data = json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
    return data['vehicles']
```

Is there any way to do get those vehicles with `ajax call` inside `def get_context(self, request):`?

I want to show some spinner in my `home_page.html` template until all vehicles are fetched.

I'm totally new to wagtail and I'm not sure how can I do that.

Comment: I'm not aware how you can do ajax call on server side? You need to write javascript to call your function here.

Comment: An ajax request needs it's own url pattern so you'll have to write a view that returns a response; a `JsonResponse` based on the code you provided. You'd then make your call by pointing the ajax url to that view.

Answer (score 0):

`get_context()` would not be relevant here.

You'll need to approach this in "traditional Django style."  In other words, you build a URL pattern and a JSON view, entirely apart from Wagtail.

On the client side, the code that is *issuing* these JSON requests in some kind of loop can receive, for example, some indication from the host (that is to say, in the returned JSON data ...) that "we're done ... there is no more data to return."  Upon seeing this, the JavaScript code could, say, "issue a signal" (with whatever JS framework you are using on that side) which would trigger a piece of JavaScript code embedded in the target page to cause it to remove the spinner.